# The end of an integer line in C

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I have to read an undefined matrix from a text file in C language, and i want to read it line by line so that each line will be an integer array.But how do i know where is the end of a line, since i can't use "\n" as in for characters?
Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace System;

typedef struct
{
    int *v;
    int n;
}vector;



int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    vector *a;
    FILE* f;
    int n = 15;
    int i = 0;
    int j,k;
    if ((f = fopen("C:\\Users\\Mirelaa\\Documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\MatriceNedefinita\\MatriceNedefinita\\Debug\\fisier2.in", "rt")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Fisierul nu poate fi deschis!");
        exit(1);

    };

    a = (vector *)malloc(n * sizeof(vector));

    while (!feof(f))
    {
        a[i].v = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        a[i].n = 0;
        //citeste rand
        //citesti fiecare element din rand
        j = 0;
        while (a[i].v[j] != '\0')// wrong!!

        {
            fscanf(f, "%d", &a[i].v[j]);
            j++;
            a[i].n = a[i].n + 1;
        }
        for (k = 0 ; k < a[i].n ; k++)
        {
            printf("%d", a[i].v[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        i++;
        if (i == n)
        {
            n = 2 * n;
            a = (vector *)realloc(a, n * sizeof(vector));
            a[i].v = (int *)realloc(a[i].v, n * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read in a line at a time, not an int at a time... then read your ints out of that line. `fgetln()` perhaps.

Comment: First of all, [in C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Then a loop like `while (!feof(...))` seldom works as expected, as the `EOF` flag isn't set until after you try to read from beyond the end of the file.

Comment: The signature of `main` is definitely **not** C.

Comment: `using namespace System`? `System::String ^`? When did this become C?

Answer (score 1):

Reading a line of integers and saving in a variable sized array is one approach.

The trouble with `fscanf(f, "%d",...` is that it first reads white-space and code loses the occurrence of `'\n'`.  Code needs to look for  it by some other means.

But rather than pack all the code in `main()`, consider helper functions.  Following C function reads one *line* of numbers and return `NULL` on 1) out-of-memory, 2) no data or conversion failure with no numbers read.  Otherwise return `vector`.  It is not limited to any line length.

```
typedef struct {
  int *v;
  size_t n;
} vector;

vector *Read_vector(vector *v1, FILE *inf) {
  v1->v = NULL;
  v1->n = 0;
  size_t size = 0;
  for (;;) {
    int number;
    int ch;
    // Check leading white-space for \n
    while (isspace(ch = fgetc(inf))) {
      if (ch == '\n') break;
    }
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) break;
    ungetc(ch, inf);
    if (1 != fscanf(inf, "%d", &number)) {
      break;
    }
    //  Is `v1` large enough?
    if (v1.n >= size) {
      size = size*2 + 1;
      vector nu;
      nu.v = realloc(v1->v, size * sizeof *nu.v);
      if (nu.v == NULL) {
        free(v1->v);
        v1->v = NULL;
        v1->n = 0;
        return NULL;
      }
      v1->v = nu.v;
    }
    v1.v[v1.n++] = number;
  }
  if (v1->n == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return v1;
}
```

With repeated calls, an array of vectors could be had.  Leave that to OP as it is very similar to the above.

Note: avoid use `while (!feof(f))`.

Answer (score 0):

I would read in a lines with fgets...(see e.g. [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm))

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

you can read a line up to $n$ characters line into a string.

This method gives you a way of loading each line individually to a string.

**Edit after good comment**

It is easier to split up the string with **strtok** and then use **atoi** to convert each bit of the string to an integer (rather than use sscanf as in my original answer).

Comment: Using `sscanf` to read an unknown number of integers will be a problem. Use of `strtok` and `atoi` will work better.

Comment: @RSahu - thanks for the useful comment - answer editted and I can see your method is **much** better